# MANOVA vs repeated measues ANOVA example

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, manova

I have the following situation (4 independent treatment groups, each group is tested for 3 dependent variables) and was wondering what would be the best to do:

1. What is the best test to do? I have always done MANOVA with post hoc for each dependent variable. Now someone said it should be repeated measures ANOVA due to sample size and limit the comparisons to only 3.
2. How do I determine if we have too many comparisons and thus have to reduce the p value?
3. Are about 7 samples per treatment group enough?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Repeated measures ANOVAs instead of repeated measures MANOVA w/ small N?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34911/repeated-measures-anovas-instead-of-repeated-measures-manova-w-small-n)